# How to store sample objects used by tests in XML YML files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit

When I create my unit tests, I use to declare and initialize a lot of sample shared objects used by the tests in one abstract class, extended by the classes with the tests.

E.g. I define the Product "phone" in the abstract class and I initialize it in a method called "init", annotated with @Before. I create the method @Test "savePhoneTest" in a child class which invokes the method "savePhone" using "phone". This object is always re-initialized and I can use it in other tests.

Is it possibile to store the sample objects in a XML / YML file? Is it a good practise? How can I retrieve the objects? I use spring boot.
Thank you

Comment: Not sure about XML/YML but you can use CSVs and various other methods when using JUnit5 Parameterized tests.

Comment: Good tutorial/example https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `XML/YAML/JSON` to store sample objects. It will help you to write lesser code for creating sample objects. Also by using this approach your test cases will become more maintainable.

I will prefer `JSON` over `XML/YAML`.

Suppose you have a `Product` class as shown below,

***Product.java***

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String brand;
}
```

You can create `JSON file` to store objects. The `JSON file` for `Product` class will look like:

***product.json***

```
{
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "Smart phone",
    "price": 60000.0,
    "brand": "SAMSUNG"
}
```

Whenever you need any object of `Product` class you can create that object using `JSON file`. Below example shows how to create java object from `JSON file`:

```
InputStream inputStream = Product.class.getResourceAsStream("/product.json");
Product product = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, Product.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Don't you know if is it possible to load sample objects like "beans" from the spring context? Does spring include any feature to do that?